# center ul navigation in header

Tags: html, css

I have tried to search for this answer as I know this has been asked many times, every previous suggestion I found is not working for me. How can I get this ul nav to be centered and not float right? Thank you!

[jsfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/kimwild/51r8tgo7/)

```
    <header>
  <div id="header-content">
    <nav class="header">
      <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
      <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#work">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

nav.header {
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    background-color: Silver;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.header ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.header li a {
    display: block;
    float: left; 
    padding: 1em;
    /*  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
.header li a:hover {
    background-color: #B5B5B5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to give the menu ul a width (*I've used min-width here), set it to a block, and set the margin to `0 auto`:

```
.header ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 450px;
}
```

And set `.header .menu` to have no float:

```
.header .menu {
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  max-height: none;
}
```

However this isn't a perfect solution, as you would need to write in breakpoints for smaller size screens.